# Uninitialized local variable in c++ dice game

Tags: c++, initialization

In this case, how would I solve this? I've looked at other posts with the same problem and I can't seem to apply it to this. I've solved this problem before but for some reason I can't remember how I did it.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <Windows.h>
#include<ctime>
using namespace std;
//Tristan Currie 11/20/14
//Dice Game
int main()
{
    //variables
    int die1, die2, dice_total, specialsum;
    char rerun, reroll;

    //intro
    cout << "Welcome to the dice game! I will now explain the rules. \nIf you land on a 7 or 11 on the first role you win. \nIf your sum is 2, 3, or 12 you lose. \nAny other role becomes your special sum. If you roll your special sum before you roll a 7 then you win. \nIf when you roll you get a 7 before your special sum then you lose. ";
    cout << "\n\nIf you would like to start the game, press enter to do your first roll. ";
    cin.get();
    cout << "\n\nRolling Dice...";

    //Suspend program for 2 seconds
    Sleep(2000);

    //seed random number generator using the system clock
    srand(static_cast<unsigned int>(time(0)));

    //generate a random number between 1 and 6
    die1 = rand() % 6 + 1;
    die2 = rand() % 6 + 1;
    dice_total = die1 + die2;
    cout << "Done!" << endl << "Dice #1 = " << die1 << "\nDice #2 = " << die2 << "\nDice Total = " << dice_total;
    cin.get();

    if ((dice_total == 7) || (dice_total == 11)) {
        cout << "Congratulations! You have won the game, press enter to end the program. ";
        cin.get();
        reroll = 'n';
    }
    else if ((dice_total == 2) || (dice_total == 3) || (dice_total == 12)) {
        cout << "You lost. Press enter to exit. ";
        cin.get();
        reroll = 'n';
    }
    else if ((dice_total != 2) || (dice_total != 3) || (dice_total != 12) || (dice_total != 7) || (dice_total != 11)) {
        cout << "This is your special sum: " << dice_total << endl;
        dice_total = specialsum;
        reroll = 'y';
    }

    while (reroll == 'y') {
        cout << "\n\nRolling Dice...";

        //Suspend program for 2 seconds
        Sleep(2000);

        //seed random number generator using the system clock
        srand(static_cast<unsigned int>(time(0)));

        //generate a random number between 1 and 6
        die1 = rand() % 6 + 1;
        die2 = rand() % 6 + 1;
        dice_total = die1 + die2;
        cout << "Done!" << endl << "Dice #1 = " << die1 << "\nDice #2 = " << die2 << "\nDice Total = " << dice_total;
        cin.get();

        if (dice_total == specialsum) {
            cout << "Congratulations! You have won the game, press enter to end the program. ";
            cin >> rerun;
            cin.get();
            reroll = 'n';
        }
        else if (dice_total == 7) {
            cout << "What a shame, you have lost the game, press enter to exit the gane. ";
            cin >> rerun;
            cin.get();
            reroll = 'n';
        }
        else {
            reroll = 'y';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does it say what local variable is uninitialized?

Comment: Whoops I forgot to say which variable. It says the problem is with specialsum.

Comment: It looks like specialsum is called, but has no value assigned to it. I'd post that as an answer, but I'm not familiar enough with C++.

Comment: I know that part but I'm just confused on how I would assign a value to it.

Comment: This line `dice_total = specialsum;` in particular. Should it be the other way around?

Comment: not sure but I'll try.

Comment: Well, I have yet again confirmed I have the intelligence of a brain-dead squirrel lol. Thanks for the contribution everyone who attempted to answer this question has put in.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I got an answer in the comments. I mixed up the order of this line: `dice_total = specialsum;`

Answer (score 0):

`int  specialsum = 0;`

Initializing integer variables to zero, or to a known value. Defining your variable like this, "int specialsum;" ,it gets lost. 
Also try `specialsum= dice_total;` instead of `dice_total=specialsum;` because "dice_total" would be equal to zero all the time. Hope this helped.